# Angular 9 - Directives, how to read attribute from component

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

this code works well with Angular 8, but not with Angular 9+.
In the following HTML component BreadcrumbComponent exists a directive appBreadcrumbs:

```
<ng-template appBreadcrumbs
             let-breadcrumb
             let-i="index">
    <li>
        some stuff
    </li>
</ng-template>
```

And the directive has this code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appBreadcrumbs]'
})
export class BreadcrumbsDirective {

  constructor(
    private view: ViewContainerRef,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>
  ) {
    // someAttribute is a @Input attribute in BreadcrumbComponent
    const attributeFromBreadcrumbComponent = this.templateRef['_parentView'].component.someAttribute;
  }
```

In Angular 9 '_parentView' doesn't exist. How can I pass the attribute? I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
<ng-template appBreadcrumbs
             [someAttribute]="someAttribute"
```

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appBreadcrumbs]'
})
export class BreadcrumbsDirective {

  @Input() someAttribute: string;
```

Note: This directive is used in many components.

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution here:
[How to Access Parent Component from Child Component in Angular 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60926745/how-to-access-parent-component-from-child-component-in-angular-9)

There is no need to pass attributes as Input to the directive.

```
parent: BreadcrumbComponent;

constructor(
    private view: ViewContainerRef,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private store: Store<any>,
    private _injector: Injector
  ) {
    this.parent = this._injector.get<BreadcrumbComponent>(BreadcrumbComponent);
    // The attributes are accesible with this.parent.someAttribute
  }
```